# Issues implementing shocks to a very simple CGE model

Tags: python, scipy

I am very new to Python and I am trying to solve a very simple CGE model. However, when trying to implement a shock to the economy, the solution yields the exact same results. I am suspicious whether I should write the code differently, or use another optimizer or something.

Here is my class in the py file:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize


class SimpleEquilibriumModel:
    def __init__(self):
        # Define objects and dimensions
        self.Y = 0  # Output (Endogen)
        self.L = 0  # Arbejdskraft (Endogen)
        self.C = 0  # Vareforbrug (Endogen)
        self.W = 0  # Løn (Endogen)
        self.P = 0  # Pris (Endogen)
        self.A = 0  # Teknologi (Eksogen)
        self.N = 0  # Befolkningen (Eksogen)


        # Define equations
        def E_L():
            return self.L == self.Y / self.A

        def E_NP():
            return self.P * self.Y == self.W * self.L

        def E_W():
            return self.L == self.N

        def E_C():
            return self.C == self.W / self.P * self.N

        def E_P():
            return self.P == 1
        
        def E_A():
            return self.A == self.W / self.P

        self.equations = [E_L, E_NP, E_W, E_C, E_P, E_A]

        # Define national accounts parameter
        self.NR = 1000

    def solve(self):
        # Initialization and calibration
        self.W = 1
        self.P = 1
        self.L = self.NR
        self.Y = self.NR
        self.N = self.L
        self.A = self.W / self.P


        # Solve the model
        from scipy.optimize import fsolve

        def model_equations(x):
            self.W, self.P, self.L, self.Y, self.N, self.A = x
            return [E() for E in self.equations]

        self.W, self.P, self.L, self.Y, self.N, self.A = fsolve(model_equations, [1, 1, self.L, self.Y, self.N, self.A])

        self.C = self.W / self.P * self.N

        return self.Y, self.L, self.C, self.W, self.P
    
    def solve_shock(self, shock_A = None):
        # Initialization and calibration
        self.W == 2
        self.P == 2
        self.L = self.NR
        self.Y = self.NR
        self.N = self.L
        self.A = (self.W / self.P)*shock_A


        # Solve the model
        from scipy.optimize import fsolve

        def model_equations(x):
            self.W, self.P, self.L, self.Y, self.N, self.A = x
            return [E() for E in self.equations]

        self.W, self.P, self.L, self.Y, self.N, self.A = fsolve(model_equations, [1, 1, self.L, self.Y, self.N, self.A])

        self.C = self.W / self.P * self.N

        return self.Y, self.L, self.C, self.W, self.P
```

This it my code in the notebook:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from nynynyny import SimpleEquilibriumModel

output, employment, consumption, wage, price = model.solve()

print("Equilibrium output:", output)
print("Equilibrium employment:", employment)
print("Equilibrium consumption:", consumption)
print("Equilibrium wage:", wage)
print("Equilibrium price:", price)

output, employment, consumption, wage, price = model.solve_shock(shock_A = 1.1)

print("New equilibrium output:", output)
print("New equilibrium employment:", employment)
print("New equilibrium consumption:", consumption)
print("New equilibrium wage:", wage)
print("New equilibrium price:", price)
```

yielding:

```
Equilibrium output: 1000.0000018014192
Equilibrium employment: 1000.0000056491614
Equilibrium consumption: 999.9999869002581
Equilibrium wage: 0.9999999925494194
Equilibrium price: 1.0000000149011612
New equilibrium output: 1000.0
New equilibrium employment: 1000.0000149011612
New equilibrium consumption: 999.9999701976781
New equilibrium wage: 0.9999999850988388
New equilibrium price: 1.0000000149011612
```

Comment: is `model = SimpleEquilibriumModel()` ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @Joao_PS

Comment: Do these results mean anything to you? /
`Equilibrium output: -5.7039175372576294e-21 /
Equilibrium employment: -1.0990687781005325e-08 /
Equilibrium consumption: -1.0990688008519588e-08 /
Equilibrium wage: 1.0000000207006297 /
Equilibrium price: 1.0 /
New equilibrium output: -1.0990688008519582e-08 /
New equilibrium employment: -1.5998848169260256e-08 /
New equilibrium consumption: -1.0990688009473645e-08 /
New equilibrium wage: 0.6869674549815936 /
New equilibrium price: 1.0 `

Comment: @Joao_PS No, because if with with a shock of a increase in productivity (A) of say 10%, the very simple model will just scare up with 10% from 1000 to 1100